# How to avoid a long switch-case statement in Go

Tags: go

I'm writing a chat bot in Go and wondering how can I avoid a long switch-case statement similar to this one:

```
switch {

// @bot search me HMAC
case strings.Contains(message, "search me"):
    query := strings.Split(message, "search me ")[1]
    return webSearch(query), "html"

// @bot thesaurus me challenge
case strings.Contains(message, "thesaurus me"):
    query := strings.Split(message, "thesaurus me ")[1]
    return synonyms(query), "html"
```

Should I define those handlers each in a separate package or should I just use structs and interfaces? Which method will allow me to have a good structure, avoid switch-case and let external developers to easier create handlers?

I think packages will be a better choice but I'm not sure how to register the handlers with the main bot. Would appreciate an example.

Comment: Separate packages is probably overkill, but if you want other devs to create handlers without modifying your code, a switch statement will not work - it's hard-coded with all available options. You want something like a map or something - take a look at the code for the standard library's HTTP mux as one example.

Comment: What is wrong with a long switch statement? That's what switch is for,

Comment: @Volker It's not dynamic for other developers.

Comment: Why not dynamically make the switch statements? `case some boolean such that the message is inside the list of keys to a dict: look up the query or whatever to do in that dict, then do it; done`.  Then have some function where devs can register stuff with your code and thus add their handlers or whatever to your groovy dict.

Comment: I want every handler to have a regex for matching, description/usage for help and a function to execute. Can't come up with a method where I wouldn't need to repeat e.g. "search me" in both Handler struct and in switch-case to execute the right function.

Comment: "look up the query or whatever to do in that dict, then do it; done" how would I put functions in a dict?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a `map[string]command` similar to how the `net/http` package registers handlers. Something akin to this:

https://play.golang.org/p/9YzHyLodAQ

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "errors"
)

type BotFunc func(string) (string, error)

type BotMap map[string]BotFunc

var Bot = BotMap{}

func (b BotMap) RegisterCommand(command string, f BotFunc) error {
    if _, exists := b[command]; exists {
        return errors.New("command already exists")
    }
    b[command] = f
    return nil
}

func (b BotMap) Execute(statement string) (string, error) {
    // parse out command and query however you choose (not this way obviously)
    command := statement[:9]
    query := statement[10:]

    return b.ExecuteQuery(command, query)
}

func (b BotMap) ExecuteQuery(command, query string) (string, error) {
    if com, exists := b[command]; exists {
        return com(query)
    }
    return "", errors.New("command doesn't exist")

}

func main() {
    err := Bot.RegisterCommand("search me", func(query string) (string, error) {
        fmt.Println("search", query)
        return "searched", nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    err = Bot.RegisterCommand("thesaurus me", func(query string) (string, error) {
        fmt.Println("thesaurus", query)
        return "thesaurused", nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    result, err := Bot.Execute("search me please")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Obviously there's a lot of checks missing here, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. However I'm not sure I understand how to do that with regexes. I'm using named captures to get user's input. Any ideas?

Comment: That's kind of a separate question, and it depends entirely on how you define your command structure. If you haven't already, sit down and try to fully define how a command is structured, which will help you determine how it can be parsed.

Comment: Well, it's not that. They really are two separate questions. Ask it in another. Proper etiquette here dictates there should be one question per post. Given the separate scope of what you are after with regex, it really is a different question.

P.S. I added a little polish to the answer.

Comment: @Maklaus plus, the answer you want for parsing out the command and the query isn't limited to just Go, it's a more broad question. It will benefit from being in it's own question with different tags to target the correct audience. Tagging something with `go` probably does more to shrink the number of people who see to question...